# Using C#, how do I stop execution of an XLL function if an assembly dependency cannot be loaded by an event handler?

Tags: c#

I have a C# XLL (Excel add-in) that (among other things) uses a 3rd-party assembly (loaded at runtime) to get data from a database. In normal circumstances, I use the ResolveEventHandler to catch the resolver and manually load the required assembly and its dependencies, like this:

```cs
private static Assembly AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{ // This is an event handler for catching missing assemblies at runtime - designed to find and load the SIMExporterEbmlImport assembly and its dependencies
    // Assume a fixed path for where the assembly is located (can update this later to look in multiple versions if needed)
    // Should also add a switch block to only look for expected dependencies in this location,
    // and throw a helpful error if some unexpected dependency is missing.
    string dependentAssemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name;
    string dependentAssemblyLocation = "C:\\ProgramData\\EB Bridging Tools\\SimExporter\\" + dependentAssemblyName + ".dll";


    // Try to load (will end up back here if lower dependencies are not met)
    try
    {
        return Assembly.LoadFile(dependentAssemblyLocation);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show(dependentAssemblyName + ".dll is missing. Please ensure it is installed to" + Common.nl
           + "C:\\ProgramData\\EB Bridging Tools\\SimExporter", "DataTool - Get EB Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The **catch** block is my first attempt at handling the case where the user's machine simply does not have the required assembly (or it is in the wrong place, perhaps). My question is: what is the best way to stop the ultimate calling method that required the event handler to be triggered i.e. not kill my whole XLL from running, but just abort whichever method was called that required the missing assembly?